# How can I use vscode to change the tab size on a file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

NOT JUST THE APPEARANCE OF TAB SIZE, THE ACTUAL TAB SIZE. I want to change how the file appears when I use "Detect Indentation". Right now it is formatted with 4-space tabs, I want 2-space tabs.

Comment: Hard tabs (ASCII 0x09) or space-based tabs?

Comment: Space tabs commentlength

Comment: "Detect indentation" overrides that. Why not just change indents in that file?